# Sometime can't open database email in iphone jailbreak

Tags: ios, iphone, email, jailbreak

I try to read Email in my iphone jailbreak. There are 2 database to get all data i need: Protected Index and Envelope Index .
My code can't open database Protected Index. But with database Envelope Index, sometime my code can't open it.
I don't know why ? Have you idea for this issue ?

My code :

```
+(sqlite3*)openDatabase:(NSString *)pathFile{
        sqlite3 * database=nil;
        pathFile = [pathFile stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if (pathFile) {
            if (sqlite3_open([pathFile UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                pathFile=nil;
                [pathFile release];
                return database;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Can't open db %@",pathFile);
                pathFile=nil;
                [pathFile release];
                return nil;
            }
        }
        return nil;
}
```